# Exported my Java game from eclipse, and it gets an error when running

Tags: java, eclipse

I made a Java game in eclipse and when I run the executable .jar it starts up, and the loading screen starts, but then it stops and hangs. I ran it using the command line: "Java -jar filename.jar" and when the loading screen stops it displays an error. This is what the cmd shows:

```
D:\>java -jar Speedrunner.jar  
60Ticks, FPS:1637  
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!  
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.utils.BufferedImageLoader.loadImage(Buffered  
ImageLoader.java:26)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.utils.ResourceLoader.loadImages(ResourceLoad  
er.java:17)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.Game.load(Game.java:100)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.Game.tick(Game.java:160)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.Game.run(Game.java:228)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  
60Ticks, FPS:1744
java.io.IOException: Can't read .\resources\Fonts\tight_pixel.ttf
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)    
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.utils.Fonts.registerFont(Fonts.java:36)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.utils.Fonts.<init>(Fonts.java:28)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.utils.ResourceLoader.loadFonts(ResourceLoader.java:30)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.Game.load(Game.java:105)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.Game.tick(Game.java:160)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.Game.run(Game.java:228)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  
60Ticks, FPS:1761  
Mon Mar 17 12:18:08 GMT 2014 INFO:Initialising sounds..  
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.  
library.path  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)  
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)  
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)  
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)  
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.<clinit>(AL.java:59)  
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore$1.run(SoundStore.java:295)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore.init(SoundStore.java:292)  
    at org.newdawn.slick.Sound.<init>(Sound.java:83)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.utils.AudioPlayer.addSound(AudioPlayer.java:29)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.utils.ResourceLoader.loadSounds(ResourceLoader.java:35)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.Game.load(Game.java:110)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.Game.tick(Game.java:160)  
    at com.daves.first_Scroller.Game.run(Game.java:228)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT - I looked in the .jar file and it contains all the Fonts and sprites it needs, and eclipse packaged all libraries needed into the .jar when I exported it.

Comment: You refered to an external file (image i guess) which is not found now so the interpreter stops... are all the path to the resources you are using correct? If yes, are you using resources in the .jar file?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this file:

```
.\resources\Fonts\tight_pixel.ttf
```

is not included on your jar. Probably it was available on your classpath when you executed your project from Eclipse, so you didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell java where to look for the LWJGL library. Add the following to the command line:

```
-Djava.library.path=path/to/dir
```

From the documentation:

> I keep getting an java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in
>   java.library.path
>
> This is because the native part is not setup correctly. Add a
>   -Djava.library.path=path/to/dir to the commandline or as an VM option in your IDE so that lwjgl is able to find the folder containing the
>   native files.

External link: http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Downloading_and_Setting_Up_LWJGL

Answer (score 0):

It seems that  .\resources\Fonts\tight_pixel.ttf is not found. That may be because before you were running you game from another path. (Or you didn't include it in your package)

Answer (score 0):

The file `.\resources\Fonts\tight_pixel.ttf` is missing in your `.jar` file.

That's, what the line `java.io.IOException: Can't read .\resources\Fonts\tight_pixel.ttf` tells you.

To solve it, integrate the folder `resources` into the path. Then it's integrated into your exported `.jar` file.